# pbkdf2 returns a hash with 128 characters instead of 64

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, cryptojs, pbkdf2

I want to create password hashes when creating users and store them to my database. My database password column stores hashes of 64 chars (`nvarchar(64)`). My hash configuration:

```
const byteAmount: number = Number(process.env.BYTE_AMOUNT) || 16;
const iterations: number = Number(process.env.ITERATIONS) || 100;
const length: number = Number(process.env.LENGTH) || 64;
const algorithm: string = process.env.ALGORITHM || 'sha512';
const conversion: string = process.env.CONVERSION || 'Hex';
```

When hashing the users plain text password I use this function

```
public hashPassword = (password: BinaryLike, passwordSalt: BinaryLike): string => {
    const { iterations, length, algorithm }: { iterations: number, length: number, algorithm: string } = passwordConfig;
    const passwordHash: string = pbkdf2Sync(password, passwordSalt, iterations, length, algorithm).toString(passwordConfig.conversion);
    return passwordHash;
}
```

Unfortunately the hash function returns a password hash with 128 characters. Is it possible to define a hash length or do I always get returned a 128 characters long hash?

Comment: You're probably get the hex-encoded hash value.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Indeed, he is converting to hex. Search for "conversion" in the code snippets he has provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameter `keylen` (`length` in your snippet) specifies number of bytes in the returned buffer. Converting this buffer to a `hex` string doubles the returned string, because each byte is represented by two characters.

If you want to get a `hex` string of 64 chars, then you must set `length = 32`.

Comment: Or perhaps he wants 64 byte hashes in which case he needs to change his DB table.

Comment: @Erwan `32 chars * 8 = 256bit`. IMHO 256bit is a sufficient size for a pbkdf2 generated key used for password based logon.

Comment: @Robert You are right of course! 256 bit is more that is needed for password hashing. There is no point in storing 512 bit password hashes.